# There is a syntax error in componentDidMount that I cannot resolve

Tags: reactjs, web-development-server

I'm creating a frontend for an API that I made, I'm using React as the frontend. When I try to use `componentDidMount(){}` I get a syntax error that says expected `;`. The `;` is expected between the `)` and `{`.
What seems to be the issue?

P.S. I'm using visual studio code - exploration

I tried to insert the semicolon, but that led to more problems.

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {

  state = {
    students: []
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.getStudents();
  }

  getStudents = _ => {
    fetch('http://localhost:4000/students')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => this.setState({students: response.data}))
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
  }

  renderStudent = ({student_id, name}) => <div key={student_id}>{name}</div>

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {students.map(this.renderStudent)}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: you meant `class App`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixxing class syntax into a component declared as a function. The componentDidMount is a method on a class component. So even adding function before it, which would fix your syntax issue, wouldn’t give you the result you are looking for.

With functions use hooks, or switch to
A class based component.

Comment: You should probably show how the `class App` declaration should look like.

Comment: They asked what the issue is. With a class you would declare your component as class App extends Component. Sorry on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

[`componentDidMount()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) is an React Component API whereas you are using a function component that doesn't have this API to be used.

Comment: It also doesn't have `state`.

Answer (score 0):

It worked..i changed function App () to class App extends Component. 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: The other poster was right though. You will need to pass params to the renderStudent method. Ideally you should make the student into a component with props rather than another render method.

Comment: yeah..im getting an error saying that students.map is not a function.